# Tkinter buttons are loosing callbacks when switching windows (class implementation) (python 3.X)

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am trying to learn how to structure tkinter GUI applications with classes. As well as that, I am also trying to replicate a simple game-like GUI, in which one does expect to have a completely different menu in each window rather than a toplevel. So what I want to do is to `__init__` my class by creating all the widgets that I am going to use and then, while jumping between windows, just forget and place them according to a window.

**Problem:** I can't reproduce behavior, that I described above, while using classes.

I have created two example programs to illustrate the problem. In the first one, switching between two windows works fine and the program replicates the behavior I am expecting:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def forget_widgets():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()


def window1():
    forget_widgets()

    my_frame1.pack()
    my_button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    my_button2.grid(row=1, column=0)


def window2():
    forget_widgets()

    my_frame2.pack()
    my_button3.grid(row=0, column=0)
    my_button4.grid(row=1, column=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    my_frame1 = ttk.Frame(root)
    my_frame2 = ttk.Frame(root)
    my_button1 = ttk.Button(my_frame1, text='Button1', command=window2)
    my_button2 = ttk.Button(my_frame1, text='Button2', command=window2)
    my_button3 = ttk.Button(my_frame2, text='Button3', command=window1)
    my_button4 = ttk.Button(my_frame2, text='Button4', command=window1)

    window1()
    root.mainloop()
```

However, when I try to wrap all this in a class - the GUI stops working after switching to window 2. It seems as if the buttons loose their callbacks. The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App:

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(master)

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Button1', command=self.window2)
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Button2', command=self.window2)
        self.button3 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Button3', command=self.window1)
        self.button4 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Button4', command=self.window1)

        self.window1()

    def window1(self):
        self.widget_forget()

        self.frame.pack()
        self.button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.button2.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def window2(self):
        self.widget_forget()

        self.frame.pack()
        self.button3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.button4.grid(column=0, row=1)

    @staticmethod
    def widget_forget():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.pack_forget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I think that the issue is related with my understanding on how classes work. I'm still rather new to programming, so there might be something simple that I am missing.

I have already tried to restructure my `widget_forget()` function in numerous ways, define it outside the App class, create callbacks with lambdas with no positive effect.

At first I thought the problem might be with the fact that I only use `forget()` on root objects, but that seems not to be the case, since example 1 works fine and the buttons in it are defined in the same way.

I have found a few answers here on stack that point to some other possible solutions (i. e. swithcing frames or using Toplevel widget), but I didn't come across a similar question to my own.

Comment: In your first example you have `my_frame1` and `my_frame2`. In the second example you only have `self.frame`. Why don't you have two frames in the second example?

Comment: Actually, adding a second frame solved my problem! So thank you. Maybe you could explain, why the program does not work with the same frame? 

Is it because I put widgets to the second frame and they stay there even if i forget the frame?

Comment: I tried to explain it in the answer I just posted, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you have two frames, `my_frame1` and `my_frame2`. You put `my_button1` and `my_button1` in `my_frame1` and `my_button3` and `my_button4` in `my_frame2`. Then, the way you switch frames is by removing all packed frames from `root` and packing the frame you want to show. Note that you don't remove the buttons from the frame, only the frame from the master window!

In your second example, you put all buttons in the same frame, `self.frame`. You then use the same strategy to try and switch frames. You remove all frames from `root`, but pack `self.frame` in both cases. Therefore, the same frame shows every time.

I guess you believed that `widget_forget()` removes the buttons from the frame(s), but it doesn't since you call it on `root` and the only direct children of `root` are the frames (`print(root.winfo_children())` outputs `[<tkinter.ttk.Frame object .!frame>, <tkinter.ttk.Frame object .!frame2>]`).

Since you don't remove the buttons from the frames, it also doesn't really make sense to `grid` them every time in the callback methods. Instead you can grid them once in their respective frames and just remove and pack the frames:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App:

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master            
        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.master)


        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text='Button1', command=self.window2)
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text='Button2', command=self.window2)
        self.button3 = ttk.Button(self.frame2, text='Button3', command=self.window1)
        self.button4 = ttk.Button(self.frame2, text='Button4', command=self.window1)
        self.button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.button2.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.button3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.button4.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.window1()

    def window1(self):
        self.widget_forget()
        self.frame1.pack()

    def window2(self):
        self.widget_forget()
        self.frame2.pack()

    def widget_forget(self):
        for widget in self.master.winfo_children():
            widget.pack_forget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

P.S. don't use `root.winfo_children()` in your second example. `root` is a variable declared outside of the class. Instead use the `master` variable passed to the class, save it in `self.master` and use that. This prevents your class from breaking when the root window is renamed outside of the class.